# How computed variable get updated in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

All:

I am pretty new to Vue, there is one question confuse me a lot:

I define a Vue instance as event bus, something like:

```js
var bus = new Vue({
    data:{
        list:[]
    },
    methods:{
        getUpdatedList(){
            var bus = this;
            LIST_AJAXRequest.then(function(updatedList){ bus.list = updatedList); bus.$emit("NEW_DATA")  })}
    }
})
```

And use this event bus in a component like:

```js
Vue.component("list-item",{
    template:"<div><input :value='myitem.value' @input='' /></div>",
    props:["item"],
    data(){
        return { myitem : this.item }
    },
    methods:{
        sendUPDATE_AJAXRequest(){ // API request to update this list item}
    },
    created(){
        var vm = this;
        bus.$on("NEW_DATA", function(){vm.myitem = Object.assign({},vm.item);} )
    }
})

Vue.component("data-list",{
    template:"<div> <list-item v-for='i in datas' :item="i"  </div>",
    data(){
        return {}
    },
    computed:{
        datas(){ return bus.list }
    }
})
```

Above is just important part of code. Basically, what I want to do is send LIST_AJAXRequest to get a list of item to show, and each list item value can be updated thru sendUPDATE_AJAXRequest and then call LIST_AJAXRequest to fetch new list back. so the update can be reflected on the list on the page.

**THE PROBLEM IS:**
After LIST_AJAXRequest fired and returns, as you can see I give the updatedList to bus.list, and notify listitem to update its myitem value by emitting a message, **but** the funny part is: the computed `datas` does not get updated before `bus.$on("NEW_DATA"`, so the item prop still the old one.

**I wonder how to control the order ?**

And when it comes to "why you do not use Vuex or watch prop", I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property watch..."

Comment: `bus.list = updatedList)` has a syntax error.

Comment: I think probably the issue is that you aren't keying your `list-item` components generated by the `v-for`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: first, where is the codes fire **LIST_AJAXRequest**? then `bus.$on("NEW_DATA", function(){vm.myitem = Object.assign({},vm.item);} )` is not neccessary, uses one watch for 'prop=item' will be better (follow Vue flow). probably you are aware of `I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property watch..."`, but `list-item.item` seems not readonly or you did something wrong in your watcher.

Answer (score 0):

1- Using arrow functions there is no need to put the `this` keyword to another variable.

2- Please read [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) article how event bus works

In the component which the request is made:

```
send_request () {
  axios.put('url_here', { data_here })
    .then(response => eventbus.$emit('data_updated', response.data))
}
```

In the component you want to listen on that event:

```
created() {
 eventBus.$on('data_updated', data => {
   console.log(data);
 })
}
```

In this example i used axios,which i recommend to use.[Take a look](https://github.com/axios/axios)